# dos batchfile to zip folders based on timespan

Tags: batch-file, zip, dos

I am looking for a way to zip folders based on a timespan of their lastmodified date and remove them afterwards

the structure is as follows

```
Folder_1 01.01.2012 12:00
- sub1
- sub2
  - file1
  - file2
Folder_2 01.01.2012 12:02
...
Folder_20202 05.05.2012 03:00
```

I want now:

1. to select all folders that are 3 months older than this month
   (e.g. lastmodified is february when current is may). An importand point is that I want to use 1st to last of month and not -90 days
2. then zip the selected folders with all subfolders and files contained into one february2012.zip
3. delete the originals of the (now) zipped files

my best idea so far is to use forfiles.exe (which takes only one date), use a generated date (1st day of 3 month ago and use the older than modifier) and create a resultextfile. Then use the resultfile as import for 7zip.exe and somehow loop over the file and delete the folders afterwards (for part 2&3, I have not yet a working code)

-- UPDATE --

At the moment I am experimenting with:

```
FORFILES /P H:\Temp\2zip /M O* /D -31.4.2012 /C "cmd /c C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe a -t7z H:\temp\x2.zip @path
```

which seems to work - but just very slowly (I guess reason is mapped drive -> 3h for 150MB)

Comment: your strategy sounds correct to me, what is your question?

Comment: it does not seem to be the "best" option - I wonder if there is a "cleaner" way to reach the goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful when working with last modified date of folders. On a FAT file system, the time stamp does not change when the contents of the folder change.

On a NTFS file system, the last modified date is updated whenever a file or folder is created or deleted within the folder. But it is not updated if a file is modified, or if a file/folder is created or deleted in a sub folder.

If you still want to move forward with your plan, then your basic strategy is pretty solid. Windows batch has very weak support for dealing with dates, so there is not much room for improvement.

The best way to parse the current date (and time if you want it) regardless of locale is to use WMIC:

```
for /f "skip=1" %%A in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do (
  set currentDateTime=%%A
  goto :exitLoop
)
:exitLoop
set year=%currentDateTime:~0,4%
set month=%currentDateTime:~4,2%
```

You should be able to use a move option of 7zip such that you don't need to delete the folder afterwards.

You should be able to eliminate the need for a temp file by processing the results of the FORFILES with a FOR /F. Or better yet, you may be able to specify the appropriate 7zip command with the FORFILES /C option.

Comment: I use now -> FORFILES /P H:\Temp\2zip /M O* /D -31.4.2012 /C "cmd /c C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe a -t7z H:\temp\x2.zip @path" <- but it is very slow (guess since I use a mapped drive - 3h for 150MB)

Comment: The Date I use is now last of previous month. because I run the command every month there should be nothing that is older than the complete previous month, since that should be already zipped and deleted